# Android manual X509 certificate chain validation

Tags: android, validation, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have implemented `javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager` in my code so I can validate my self-signed cert, which my software accesses.  However, I still need to validate some other "standard" website SSL certificates.  I am using `CertPathValidator.validate()` to do that, but I just realized that one cert chain I am being passed (for maps.googleapis.com) doesn't actually contain the complete chain - it contains the whole chain but the Root CA (Equifax), which does exist on the phone, but `validate()` still fails because (apparently) it's not explicitly in the chain.  What am I missing here, so that the validation succeeds?  Thanks for any input.

Edit - Relevant code (with exception checking removed):

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// chain is of type X509Certificate[]
CertPath cp = cf.generateCertPath(Arrays.asList(chain));

CertPathValidator cpv = CertPathValidator.getInstance(CertPathValidator.getDefaultType());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
ks.load(is, null);

PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(ks);
CertPathValidatorResult cpvr = cpv.validate(cp, params);
```

Comment: Some more detail: I get a `CertPathValidatorException` from the call to `validate()` with the error, **org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: No CRLs found for issuer "OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing your own TrustManager is generally a bad idea. The better way is to add your certificates to a keystore, and add it as a trust store. See [this](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html) for an example of how to do it.

You probably need to add the default trust store to your validator. Also, Android does not do revocation (CRL) checking by default, so if you enabled it, you need to get the related CRL's manually. Post your code.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I will check that out.

Comment: This looks to be the correct answer, but I am using 3rd-party libs that call `DefaultHttpClient` and I don't want to get into recompiling them, so I will just let my calls to maps.googleapis.com be insecure at this point. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Nikolay, "Implementing your own TrustManager is generally a bad idea."
I agree. But, we need verify certificate with CRL. Android doesn't it. How can we solve it?